# I want to redirect to login page when page expired(419) display

Tags: laravel

I added this code in handler.php

```
if ($exception instanceof \Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException) {
        return redirect()->route('login_page');
    }
```

but when session destroyed, it does not redirect to login page.

Comment: then dd the $exception to check 1- if the exception runs throu the handler 2- what is the class of $exception in that case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are doing it in a wrong section so in your `Handler.php` class create a `report` method

**Laravel 7 and higher**

```php
public function report(Throwable $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof \Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException) {
        return redirect()->route('login_page');
    }
}
```

**Laravel 6 and below**

```php
public function report(Exception $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof \Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException) {
        return redirect()->route('login_page');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In Laravel 8 or higher, go to `app/Exceptions` edit `Handler.php` and update the register method as follows-

```
 public function register()
 {
     $this->renderable(function (\Exception $e) {
         if ($e->getPrevious() instanceof \Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException) {
             return redirect()->route('login');
         };
     });
 }
```

in `return redirect()->route('login');` change you `login` to your login route.

Comment: I use v9.2 and this has worked, thanks!