# Laravel How to capture 419 then redirect to different login page

Tags: laravel

I have googled a lot. Most of the posts says, set csrf,
1 meta tag, name="csrf-token",  content="{{ csrf_token() }}"
2 @csrf inside form tag
3 exclude the route

Another workround, to extend the time.

```
Route::get('refresh-token', function(){
    return csrf_token();
});
```

Then use javascript write setInterval to get new csrf...

These I have did. But I want better and more simple solution:

**If 419 happens, redirect to login page.**
Frontend to http://mysite/login
Admin to http://mysite/admin/login

**How to capture 419 and the current section (admin or not) then redirect??**

ChatGPT tells me to use App\Exceptions\Handler.  It says render(), but there is register() in laravel10. I think the code is the same inside the function.

It use:

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
```

My laravel was

```
public function register()
```

I change to

```
public function register(Request $request)
```

It says

```
'App\Exceptions\Handler::register()' is not compatible with method 'Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler::register()
```

I use

```
public function register()
{
    $this->reportable(function (Throwable $e) {
        //
    });

    $request = new Request;
    $segment = $request->segment();
    echo '<pre>', print_r($segment, 1), "</pre>"; exit;

    $this->renderable(function (\Exception $e) {
        if ($e->getPrevious() instanceof \Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException) {
            return redirect()->route('lang.admin.login');
        };
    });
}
```

It give me white page.

---

I think I found the solution. Add $request inside renderable():

```
public function register()
{
    $this->reportable(function (Throwable $e) {
        //
    });

    $this->renderable(function (\Exception $e, $request) {
        $segments = $request->segments();

        if ($e->getPrevious() instanceof \Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException) {
            if($segments[1] == 'admin'){
                return redirect()->route('admin.login');
            }else{
                return redirect()->route('login');
            }
        };
    });
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I want to redirect to login page when page expired(419) display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66262397/i-want-to-redirect-to-login-page-when-page-expired419-display)

Comment: [Laracasts: how to redirect to login page when 419 error](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-redirect-to-login-page-when-419-error)

Comment: That is already in my content. How to know if now is admin section or not??

Comment: Why do you have `exit;` in there? That's most likely the cause of the 'white page'. [exit — Output a message and terminate the current script](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php)

Comment: echo ... exit; is my debug method. sometimes echo 123;exit; or echo $myvar; exit; just to see what's wrong at this moment.

Comment: I think I have found the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to capture 419: use app\Exceptions\Handler.php
How to get current url segment: use $request

app\Exceptions\Handler.php

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
...

public function register()
{
    $this->reportable(function (Throwable $e) {
        //
    });

    $this->renderable(function (\Exception $e, $request) {
        $segments = $request->segments();

        if ($e->getPrevious() instanceof \Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException) {
            if($segments[1] == 'admin'){
                return redirect()->route('admin.login');
            }else{
                return redirect()->route('login');
            }
        };
    });
}
```

We don't need to define $request, just put it inside
renderable(function (\Exception $e, $request))

Answer (score 0):

Try the `TokenMismatchException` error in `renderable` callback like this

```
$this->renderable(function (TokenMismatchException $e, $request) {
    $segments = $request->segments();
    if(isset($segments[1]) && $segments[1] == 'admin'){
        return redirect()->route('admin.login');
    }else{
        return redirect()->route('login');
    }
});
```